# How to interpret @vars and other special comment blocks in email templates?

Tags: magento-1, email, email-templates, transactional-mail

In email template files, there are these comments which obviously have some special meaning:

```
<!--@subject @-->
<!--@vars    @-->
<!--@styles  @-->
```

1. How does Magento interpret these special comments?
2. What is this JSON-like syntax and how does it work?

   ```
   {"store url=\"\"":"Store Url", "var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url"}
   ```
3. How do I determine if I have to use a $ when referring to variables?

   ```
   <td><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" /></a></td>
   ...
   <h1>Deer, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}</h1>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is a mini template language that I believe can be traced by looking through `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` if you specifically check out `loadDefault` you'll see those three patterns.
2. This json like template'ing syntax is explained reasonably [in the documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index).
3. The available variables are listed in the above documentation. From there you should see which have the $ and which don't (I'm not entirely sure on the distinction).